# Joining pandas data-frames of different lengths, different key id and duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, join, duplicates

I have 2 data frames. One is has around 200000 rows whereas other us 500000. I want to join in such a way that the id which are common in both dataframe should be kept.

Another thing is i also have duplicated

```
test = pd.merge(login, watched, how='inner', left_on=['id'], right_on=['user_id'])
In [114]:

test.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 500000 entries, 0 to 5000001
Data columns (total 14 columns):
```

but i get same amount of entries as of big dataframe. How can sort of user which are common in both dataframes.

Comment: shouldn't it be `how='inner'` for **common** id's? Also `how='inner'` is the default option for `merge`.

Comment: @QuangHoang indeed it was inner with same output as mentioned

Comment: Can you make sure that there are no duplicates on `id` and `user_id` in both dfs. Dups might also result in increase of data even with inner join.

Comment: This `Int64Index: 500000 entries, 0 to 5000001` doesn't look right. Also, since you have duplicated `id`, it's normal that the merged data has bigger size.

Comment: @QuangHoang so this correct join? and how should i get unique values then?

Comment: What is the output of `login['id'].duplicated().sum()` and `watched['user_id'].duplicated().sum()`?

Comment: `drop_duplicates`. Or if you only need the list of common id: `np.intersect1d(login['id'], watached['user_id'])`.